# amazon-efs failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: ****-pv-public
    namespace: ****
spec:
    storageClassName: efs-sc
    capacity:
        storage: 3Gi
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    csi:
        driver: efs.csi.aws.com
        volumeHandle: fs-***
        volumeAttributes:
            path: /***/public
```

```
Mounting arguments: -t efs -o tls fs-2f974c54:/****/public /var/lib/kubelet/pods/9784d80e-4678-4b0b-96ae-a5cccf7db7a0/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/******/mount
Output: Could not start amazon-efs-mount-watchdog, unrecognized init system "aws-efs-csi-dri"
b'mount.nfs4: mounting 127.0.0.1:/****/public failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? What did you try? Did any of posted here solutions help you?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: This error shows up if the `volumeHandle` of the PV resource points to an EFS Access point (`fsap-...`) which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, how I fixed it
first, create an access point

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
        name: **-pv-public
        namespace: laravel-test
    spec:
        storageClassName: efs-sc
        capacity:
            storage: 3Gi
        accessModes:
            - ReadWriteMany
        persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
        csi:
            driver: efs.csi.aws.com
            volumeHandle: fs-**::fsap-***
```

and fs-::fsap-* (::) not (:)

Answer (score 0):

does the **`sub directory exists`** which you're mounting? also can you try adding like this?
As per the example the path should exists.

```
Replace FileSystemId of the EFS filesystem ID that needs to be mounted. And replace Path with a existing path on the filesystem.
```

you can refer this link:

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/volume_path

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-****-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  mountOptions:
    - tls
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-*****:/****
```